# How to make if statements in bat

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I found some instructions to eject the disc drive on the Internet and I would like to know how to add a condition like typing a command to open it by means of an if statement.
Here it is the code, for the moment I just repeat an infinite loop waiting 10 seconds in each iteration.

```
@echo off
:open
echo Set oWMP = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")  >> %temp%\temp.vbs
echo Set colCDROMs = oWMP.cdromCollection       >> %temp%\temp.vbs
echo For i = 0 to colCDROMs.Count-1             >> %temp%\temp.vbs
echo colCDROMs.Item(i).Eject                    >> %temp%\temp.vbs
echo next                                       >> %temp%\temp.vbs
echo oWMP.close                                 >> %temp%\temp.vbs
%temp%\temp.vbs
timeout /t 1
del %temp%\temp.vbs
timeout /t 10
goto open
exit
```

Comment: This is a batch file that creates a Vbscript and then executes the Vbscript. Why not just do the whole thing in Vbscript. Regardless of that you have not asked a specific question.

Comment: Open a command prompt window and run `if /?` to get help about __IF__ and its syntax. If you want to prompt the user for something, use `set /P "variable=prompt text: "`. Get help on command __SET__ by running in command prompt window `set /?`. And [Squashman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694/squashman) is absolutely right with his note. Why not coding everything directly in a VBScript?